# Fraction in Listing results in wrong frame

Tags: math-mode, listings, fractions

If I try to integrate fractions in my listing, the frame around the listing becomes discontinuous. Is there a way to fix it, without turning the `\frac` into a one line `/`? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{ %
language=C++,                % choose the language of the code
basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\footnotesize,      % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
commentstyle=\color{DarkGreenComment}\ttfamily,
%keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it is 1 each line will be numbered
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
frame=single,           % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,           % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,        % sets automatic line breaking
alsoletter={]},
breakatwhitespace=false,    % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
emph={createBaseElement, createJunction},
morekeywords={TreeGraph,Graph,IndexGraph,HashGraph,CompressedGraph,EdgeMap,NodeMap,EdgeEntry},  
%breakatwhitespace,
escapeinside={\%*}{*)}          % if you want to add a comment within your code
}



\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:pcgoptimized}, mathescape=true ,caption={Version of PCG as employed by NAG library.}] 
$\mathbf{r}_0 = \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{A} * \mathbf{x}_0$
$i = 0$

do {
    solve $\mathbf{C} * \mathbf{z}_{i} = \mathbf{r}_{i}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbf{z}_{i} = \mathbf{C}^{-1} * \mathbf{r}_{i}$
    $i = i + 1$
    if ($i==1$)
        $\mathbf{p}_i = \mathbf{z}_{i-1}$
    else {  
        $b_i = \frac{\displaystyle \mathbf{r}_{i-1}^T * \mathbf{z}_{i-1}}{\displaystyle \mathbf{r}_{i-2}^T * \mathbf{z}_{k-2}}$
        $\mathbf{p}_k = \mathbf{z}_{i-1} + b_i * \mathbf{p}_{i-1}$
    }
    $\mathbf{q}_i = \mathbf{A} * \mathbf{p}_k$
    $a_i = \frac{\displaystyle \mathbf{r}_{i-1}^T * \mathbf{z}_{i-1}}{\displaystyle \mathbf{p}_k^T * \mathbf{q}_i}$
    $\mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{x}_{i-1} + a_i * \mathbf{p}_i$
    $\mathbf{r}_i = \mathbf{r}_{i-1} - a_i * \mathbf{q}_i$
}
while (termination criterion not fulfilled)  
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now that is PSEUDO-code!  As a quick fix you might be able to replace the frame with an overlaid frame, perhaps using \tikzmark in two corners.

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail? I did not use tikz many often. Thanks.

Comment: According to the manual (page 55) the only solution involves \verbatimwrite and \mdframed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the fudge factors `(-3.5pt,5pt)` and `(3pt,14.5pt)`.  I tried digging through the source code for things like `\lst@sep` or `\lst@skip` but couldn't find anything useful.

Don't forget to run it twice.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{caption}

\lstset{ %
language=C++,                % choose the language of the code
basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\footnotesize,      % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
commentstyle=\color{DarkGreenComment}\ttfamily,
%keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it is 1 each line will be numbered
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
frame=single,           % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,           % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,        % sets automatic line breaking
alsoletter={]},
breakatwhitespace=false,    % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
emph={createBaseElement, createJunction},
morekeywords={TreeGraph,Graph,IndexGraph,HashGraph,CompressedGraph,EdgeMap,NodeMap,EdgeEntry},  
%breakatwhitespace,
escapeinside={\%*}{*)}          % if you want to add a comment within your code
}



\begin{document}

\noindent\tikzmark{start}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:pcgoptimized}, mathescape=true] 
$\mathbf{r}_0 = \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{A} * \mathbf{x}_0$
$i = 0$

do {
    solve $\mathbf{C} * \mathbf{z}_{i} = \mathbf{r}_{i}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbf{z}_{i} = \mathbf{C}^{-1} * \mathbf{r}_{i}$
    $i = i + 1$
    if ($i==1$)
        $\mathbf{p}_i = \mathbf{z}_{i-1}$
    else {  
        $b_i = \frac{\displaystyle \mathbf{r}_{i-1}^T * \mathbf{z}_{i-1}}{\displaystyle \mathbf{r}_{i-2}^T * \mathbf{z}_{k-2}}$
        $\mathbf{p}_k = \mathbf{z}_{i-1} + b_i * \mathbf{p}_{i-1}$
    }
    $\mathbf{q}_i = \mathbf{A} * \mathbf{p}_k$
    $a_i = \frac{\displaystyle \mathbf{r}_{i-1}^T * \mathbf{z}_{i-1}}{\displaystyle \mathbf{p}_k^T * \mathbf{q}_i}$
    $\mathbf{x}_i = \mathbf{x}_{i-1} + a_i * \mathbf{p}_i$
    $\mathbf{r}_i = \mathbf{r}_{i-1} - a_i * \mathbf{q}_i$
}
while (termination criterion not fulfilled)  
\end{lstlisting}% automatic par
\hspace*{\fill}\tikzmark{end}\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
\captionof{lstlisting}{Version of PCG as employed by NAG library.}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red] ($(pic cs:start)+(-3.5pt,5pt)$) rectangle ($(pic cs:end)+(3pt,14.5pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I solved it in a very similar way by drawing a rectangle in tkiz and moved it over the Listing. A grouped both into a minipage and set it as a floating object. This seems to work.